# Trouble with not reading specific information using scanner

Tags: java

While reading a text file with scanner, I only want to have a certain amount of info. all the rest I don't want to have.

Example:

1)
Bruges, Belgium;Antwerp, Belgium;107 km
OUTPUT --> String city1 = Bruges, String city2 = Antwerp, Double distance = 107

2)
Bruges, Belgium;Brussels, Belgium;105 km
OUTPUT --> String city1 = Bruges, String city2 = Brussels, Double distance = 105

3)
Ixelles, Belgium;Charleroi, Belgium;71.6 km
OUTPUT --> String city1 = Ixelles, String city2 = Charleroi, Double distance = 71.6

What I have found:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
    String city1 = lineScanner.next();
    lineScanner.skip(", Belgium;");
    String city2= lijnScanner.next();
    lineScanner.skip(", Belgium;");
    double km = Integer.parseInt(lineScanner.next());
    lineScanner.skip(" km");
    this.voegToe(new TweeSteden(city1, city2),km);
    lineScanner.close();
}
```

Voegtoe: a method that puts the information into a Map.
TweeSteden: an object that contains the two cities as Strings.

Tanks for the help.

Comment: what is your question here?

Comment: How can I change my code so that it works? now I get an error at: lineScanner.skip(", Belgium"). I want to read in the first city, then ", Belgium" not. Then city2 and ", Belgium" not. At last I need the distance (double), but not "km".

Comment: what error does it throws ?

Comment: NoSuchElementExeption

Comment: it `the specified pattern is not found` in the input . so just try without special characters.something like this `lineScanner.skip(" Belgium");`

Comment: Seems to solve that problem. Now it has like input: String city1 = Bruges,Antwerp. No problem, just a simple split and I have the two cities. Tanks for that. I only have a weird thing going on. Eclipse Strikethroughs some lines in the JUnit tests. Don't know why yet.

Comment: yes you can split it easily now. will explain why it was throwing the error in previous case with my answer . i guess it would help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lineScanner.skip(", Belgium;");`

what java docs say for `skip` method,

***skip(java.util.regex.Pattern) methods operate independently of the delimiter pattern. These methods will attempt to match the specified pattern with no regard to delimiters in the input and thus can be used in special circumstances where delimiters are not relevant. These methods may block waiting for more input.***

Previously you were trying to match the pattern through `public Scanner skip(Pattern pattern)` and that is the reason why `NoSuchElementExeption` was thrown .

so `public Scanner skip(String pattern)` will look for the string to skip.

To know more about those methods look [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#skip%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)

Hope this helps!!